# MySQL function LENGTH() inside a Prodedure doesnt return string length as bytes

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures, mariadb, etl

I need to make a procedure and as a core point of it I must get the byte lenght of a string with double byte chars. But for a very very strange reason when I use the LENGHT() function within a procedure on my MySQL v5.5.50 instance, I get a count of the total number of characters.... Not a byte count of the string.

This is the "testing" function (phpmyadmin export):

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `prueba`(`cadena` VARCHAR(256)) RETURNS longtext CHARSET latin1
    NO SQL
BEGIN

RETURN LENGTH(cadena);

END
```

This function returns:

```
SELECT prueba ("à");

prueba ("à")
=============
1
```

What are I doing wrong? :(

This is the real work function:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS TRACKLIST;
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION TRACKLIST(v_codAlbum INT) RETURNS LONGTEXT

BEGIN

DECLARE v_finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE v_salida LONGTEXT DEFAULT "";
DECLARE v_track LONGTEXT DEFAULT "";
DECLARE v_artist LONGTEXT DEFAULT "";

DECLARE v_total_tracks INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE v_tracknum INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE v_titlelen INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE v_artistlen INTEGER DEFAULT 0;

DECLARE curs CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT Titulo 
    FROM tracks t1 INNER JOIN artistas t2 
    where t1.IdContenido = t2.IdContenido 
    and idAlbum = v_codAlbum
    and NumeroTrack > 0 
    order by numerotrack asc;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET v_finished = 1;

-- Recupero el numero de Canciones (tracks)
SELECT count(*) INTO v_total_tracks 
FROM tracks t1 INNER JOIN artistas t2 
where t1.IdContenido = t2.IdContenido 
and idAlbum = v_codAlbum
and NumeroTrack > 0; 

-- Recupero el nombre del Artista
SELECT t2.Descripcion INTO v_artist
FROM albumes t1 INNER JOIN interpretes t2 
WHERE t1.idInterprete = t2.idInterprete 
and t1.idAlbum = v_codAlbum;

-- Inicializo la estructura de datos de tracklist
SET v_salida = CONCAT('a:', v_total_tracks, ':{');
SET v_tracknum = 0;

OPEN curs;

-- Comienzo LOOP para agregar las canciones (tracks)
get_tracks: LOOP
    FETCH curs INTO v_track;
    IF v_finished = 1 THEN
    LEAVE get_tracks;
    END IF;

    -- Calculo el tamaño del string de nombre de cancion y nombre de Artista, necesario para agregar a la estructura de datos
    SET v_titlelen = LENGTH(v_track);
    SET v_artistlen = LENGTH(v_artist);


    -- Estructura de datos con Nombre de Cancion y Nombre de Artista, solo estos datos
    SET v_salida = CONCAT(v_salida,'i:',v_tracknum,';a:5:{');
    SET v_salida = CONCAT(v_salida,'s:24:"releasetrack_track_title";s:',v_titlelen,':"',v_track,'";');
    SET v_salida = CONCAT(v_salida,'s:24:"releasetrack_artist_name";s:',v_artistlen,':"',v_artist,'";');

    -- Este puto campo es requerido para que todo funcione.
    SET v_salida = CONCAT(v_salida,'s:21:"releasetrack_mp3_demo";s:0:"";');

    -- Estos campos solo son requeridos para que funcione la aplicacion.
    -- SOLO SE INCLUYEN EN LA CANCION "0"

    IF v_tracknum = 0 THEN
    SET v_salida = CONCAT(v_salida,'s:18:"releasetrack_scurl";');
    SET v_salida = CONCAT(v_salida,'s:0:"";');
    SET v_salida = CONCAT(v_salida,'s:19:"releasetrack_buyurl";');
    SET v_salida = CONCAT(v_salida,'s:0:"";');
    END IF;

    -- Cierro Estructura para datos de una cancion
    SET v_salida = CONCAT(v_salida,'}');

    SET v_tracknum = v_tracknum + 1;
END LOOP get_tracks;
CLOSE curs; 

-- Cierro Estructura de toda la lista de Canciones  
SET v_salida = CONCAT(v_salida,'}');

-- 
RETURN v_salida;

END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Here are details about the functions' charset and encoding

[DETAILS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXUKr.png)

[DETAILS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8FPp.png)

Comment: Did you really misspell `LENGTH()`?

Comment: None of that is correct syntax for creating a function in MySQL. The command is `CREATE FUNCTION` and you need to specify the return type with a `RETURNS INT` clause. Please show the actual function definition that doesn't report a syntax error.

Comment: The problem seems to be that `cadena` isn't being seen as a multi-byte string in the function. `RETURN ORD(cadena)` returns `225` rather than `50081`.

Comment: I will post the correct "testing" function and other more complex, the real work fuction. Sorry for  misspelling. :)

Comment: It probably has something to do with the collation of the argument. it seems to change from a Unicode string to a UTF-8 string.

Comment: @Barmar 
I added more information in the post :)

Comment: That's way more than needed.

Comment: It's strange because in the real work function (the second that I posted) the multi-byte characters are preserved in the output, but LENGTH function count every chars as single byte. I really need a multi-byte count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Please look at `SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE`.  I think you will find that `cadena` is assumed to be `CHARACTER SET latin1`, not utf8.
- In latin1, `à` is only 1 byte (Hex `E0`).  utf8 would be 2 bytes (hex `C3A0`).
- It seems strange to be returning a numeric values as `LONGTEXT`.  (This is unrelated to the question.)

Comment: I found a workarround, but I am searching for a elegant solution. I thing it is on the function's declaration.

´   DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS prueba;
   DELIMITER //
   CREATE FUNCTION prueba(cadena VARCHAR(256)) RETURN LONGTEXT
   BEGIN
   RETURN LENGTH(CONVERT(cadena USING utf8));
   END //
   DELIMITER ;´